# KeyTyped key not showing key

Tags: processing

I am trying to convert from processing to processingjs and have something I just can't understand.

In processing the following code returns whichever letter you type in, though in processingjs it just comes back with the keycode value but I need the letter not the code.

```
String name="";

void setup(){
 size(200,200);
}

void draw(){  
}

void keyPressed() {
  if(key==ENTER) {
  name="";
}
else {
 name+=key;
 println(name);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching and the above answer I've found the answer here peepproject.com/forums/thread/266/view more eloquently than I. Basically the solution is to convert the `int` to a `char()` before constructing a `String` and putting it into an `array`.

Comment: the processing way `name += char(key);`, the java way `name +=(char)key;` or the processing.js way `name += char(key);` or the javascript way (to mix with processing js) `name += String.fromCharCode(key);"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the char conversion function in Processing and Processing.js:

http://processingjs.org/reference/char_/

The reason why it's displaying as a number is this line:

```
char x = 97; //supposed to be an 'a'
```

Does a cast in Java (may require char x = (char)97).

However in processing.js it is executed as:

```
var x = 97;
```

Since javascript has dynamic typing. You therefore need to explicitly force type casts such as from int->char.

Comment: After hours of searching and the above answer i've found the answer here http://peepproject.com/forums/thread/266/view more eloquently than I. Basically the solution is to convert the int to a char() before constructing a string and putting it into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `name += key`, try `name += key.toString()`.

Processing's `println` automatically does type conversion for you, so the `char` value of `PApplet.key` gets printed as a letter.  JavaScript string concatenation works differently; the integer value of `PApplet.key` will be appended to the string as an integer and will not automatically be converted to a string.  You have to do it manually.